# Amazon Connect - How to generate report based on CTRs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

We have created a contact centre with two contact flows and 1 customer queue flow. Under Metrics there are multiple report types which focus on the Queue or Agents. But what I need is to get a report based on the Customer's choice for the Get customer Input blocks. ie., path taken by the customer at each intersection. Is there a way to achieve this ?

Example:
customer selected option A at level 1 and Option 3 at Level 2, contact flow name etc.. I believe these info will reside in CTRs(Contact attributes) but how to get a cumulative report on all records. Because as far I checked we can only get one contact at a time using Contact search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stream the CTR data to a redshift database using the streaming feature in Amazon Connect. The general steps are to create a kinesis stream and then turn on streaming in Amazon connect and attach the kinesis stream.

There is a quickstart to help set this up here: https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/connect/data-streaming/